# How to rename file with pattern using batch script

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

For example I have a .txt file named pair.txt.

Example:

```
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_FFF_GGG_HHH.idoc.xml            AAAA
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_FFF_111_222.idoc.xml            BBBB
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_FFF_333_444.idoc.xml            CCCC
```

Now this file contains 2 columns of filenames. First column will be the pattern to rename the second column. Now I want to use the right side of 6th and 7th "_" as pattern. The final filenames of the files in the second column must be:

```
AAAA.GGG_HHH
BBBB.111_222
CCCC.333_444
```

As you noticed, I didn't include the .idoc.xml part. Now I want to put the code within this for statement:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('type c:\user\pair.txt') do (
        echo Renaming file : %%b
        )
```

How will I able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%a in ("c:\user\pair.txt") do (
    for /f "tokens=7,8 delims=_." %%c in ("%%a") do (
        echo Renaming file : %%b = %%b.%%c_%%d
    )
)
```

Use a second `for` command to split the first column and then use the adecuated tokens

Comment: Will this part "delims=_." means start and end?

Comment: @PeterS, no, it indicates the characters used to split the line into tokens. The `tokens=7,8` indicates, from all the available tokens after split, what to retrieve into the `for` replaceable parameters.

Comment: How can I redirect the new file to my desired directory for this?

Comment: I tried this after the echo but its not working
ren "C:\FileRename\Outputs\%%b" "C:\FileRename\New Outputs\%%b.%%c_%%d"

Comment: @PeterS, `ren` is used to change the name and extension of a existing file, so, the first parameter of `ren` command is used to locate the file, the second parameter is only the final file name and extension, **without path** as the file will not be moved, just renamed. Maybe instead of `ren` you need to use `copy` or `move`

Comment: Ok i got it by using
rename "C:\FileRename\Outputs\%%b" %%b.%%c_%%d I didnt know that second parameter must not contain path. By the way. im confused with the "delims=_." ( dot ). What will be the role of the (dot) here? Also, im looking forward to the this tool improved. Next step must be to have the user to be able to enter the option and not editing the code for the delimeter to be used.

Comment: @PeterS, when the first column is tokenized, what will separate `HHH` from `idoc` so `idoc` is not included in the token?